# Html - Css Aligning 3 Divs in a window

Tags: php, html, css, styles, css-float

My Current project consists of a window which includes **a Horizontal Navigation Menu, a Vertical Navigation Menu, a set of buttons and finally a Table** .

So the structure is like this

[image]

**1. `Div` of Horizontal Navigation Menu

2. `Div` of Vertical Navigation Menu

3. `Div` with a set of buttons

4. `Div` with a Table inside**

I tried it today, as per my work, The 1st and 2nd `DIVS` positioned correctly. when come to 3rd and 4th `DIVS` its not positioning correctly.

so i tried code like following

```
<div style="float:left;"> // That white window
    <div style="float:right"> // Yellow div
        buttons.....
    </div>
    <div style="float:left"> // Orange div
        <Table>....</table>
    </div>
</div>
```

but 3rd div not aligning properly when I tested it in systems with different resolutions. So

1. how to align that 3rd div to the EXTREME RIGHT of window and 4th div to the Centre of the window(centre of above white window)
2. and how to make 3rd and 4th Window fixed at that position even Window minimized to smaller.

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post all the css and html.

Comment: Maybe you need `position:fixed` on 3rd div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmtyjhpq/3/embedded/result/

Else post some of you CSS also. then i can have a look again. Greeetz

```
    #wrapper
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;    
}

.divone
{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.divto
{
    position: relative;
    height:900px;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
}

.divthree
{
    float:right;
    width:250px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:yellow;
    display:block;
    margin-right:50px;
    position:relative;
}

.divfor{
    float:right;
    width:600px;
     height:600px;
    background-color:gray;
    margin-top:180px;
}
```